# What is the equivalent terminal commands for installing Languages?

Tags: command-line, language-support

I know I can install any Language and fonts by going clicking Dash->Settings->Language Support->Install/Remove Languages but how can I do this if I'm using Ubuntu Server and I do not have a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

If for example you want to install Arabic, you would, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-ar
```

For complete list of ISO language codes see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)